# VC++ debugging: is it possible to skip cursor?

Tags: c++, debugging, mfc, visual-studio-debugging

As we all know, in debugging mode, Visual C++ support "Run to Cursor" feature, so, I'm curious to know whether it support simillar feature "Skip cursor". In other words, my app just skip the line of code.

Anybody can help me?

PS: I'm using Visual C++ 2010.

Comment: that is not "similar" at all. Skipping a line of code might serisouly affect the program (what if your variable declaration/initialization is skipped??) while "Run to Cursor" is the same as putting a breakpoint and running to there.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do this easily.

Once you're at a breakpoint, you can right-click on a line of code just like you do to "Run to cursor", but instead, choose "Set next statement".

It's [explained on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09yze4a9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You can run to the previous line, and then skip over it using 'set next statement'.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know such feature. But i think you can:

1. comment current line of code
2. use "Apply code change".
3. "step over"